# R: aggregate columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
> head(df)
            Memory    Memory    Memory    Memory    Memory     Naive     Naive
10472501  6.075714  5.898929  6.644946  6.023901  6.332126  8.087944  7.520194
10509163  6.168941  6.495393  5.951124  6.052527  6.404401  7.152890  8.335509
10496091 10.125575  9.966211 10.075613 10.310952 10.090649 11.803949 11.274480
10427035  6.644921  6.658567  6.569745  6.499243  6.990852  8.010784  7.798154
10503695  8.379494  8.153917  8.246484  8.390747  8.346748  9.540236  9.091740
10451763 10.986717 11.233819 10.643245 10.230697 10.541396 12.248487 11.823138
```

and I'd like to find the mean of the `Memory` columns and the mean of the `Naive` columns. The `aggregate` function aggregates rows. This `data.frame` could potentially have a large number of rows, and hence transposing then applying `aggregate` by the `colnames` of the original `data.frame` strikes me as bad, and is generally annoying:

```
> head(t(aggregate(t(df),list(colnames(df)), mean)))
         [,1]       [,2]      
Group.1  "Memory"   "Naive"   
10472501 "6.195123" "8.125439"
10509163 "6.214477" "7.733625"
10496091 "10.11380" "11.55348"
10427035 "6.672665" "8.266854"
10503695 "8.303478" "9.340436"
```

What's the blindingly obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: keen eyed among you will notice that 8.12 is not the mean of 8.08 and 7.52: there are a few more columns in reality. Not many more though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am a big advocate of reformatting data so that it's in a "long" format. The utility of the long format is especially evident when it comes to problems like this one. Fortunately, it's easy enough to reshape data like this into almost any format with the `reshape` package.

If I understood your question right, you want the mean of `Memory` and `Naive` for every row. For whatever reason, we need to make column names unique for `reshape::melt()`.

```
colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), 1:ncol(df), sep = "_")
```

Then, you'll have to create an `ID` column. You could either do

```
df$ID <- 1:nrow(df)
```

or, if those rownames are meaningful

```
df$ID <- rownames(df)
```

Now, with the `reshape` package

```
library(reshape)
df.m <- melt(df, id = "ID")
df.m <- cbind(df.m, colsplit(df.m$variable, split = "_", names = c("Measure", "N")))
df.agg <- cast(df.m, ID ~ Measure, fun = mean)
```

`df.agg` should now look like your desired output snippit.

Or, if you want just the overall means across all the rows, Zack's suggestion will work. Something like

```
m <- colMeans(df)
tapply(m, colnames(df), mean)
```

You could get the same result, but formatted as a dataframe with

```
cast(df.m, .~variable, fun = mean)
```

Comment: Giving Jo the tick because this seems to be the Right Way to do things, so thanks very much! But yes, as John says, the obvious thing I was missing was simply the rowMeans function, which is something I won't forget again!

Comment: Erm - quick question. Any idea why `s <- cast(df.m, ID ~ variable, fun = var)` returns me a bunch of zeros, when `fun = mean` seems to work fine and 'fun=sum` also works? The variance of these columns is def not zero.

Comment: Good catch! I don't know what the deal was, but since the column names weren't unique, they didn't melt correctly. I've edited my answer so that it should work now!

Comment: I've spun this out into a more general question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356923/r-reshape-variance-of-columns-of-a-data-frame Fancy expanding on this a bit?

Answer (score 4):

What about something like

```
l <-lapply(unique(colnames(df)), function(x) rowMeans(df[,colnames(df) == x]))



df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, l)
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! This is what some part of my brain was telling me existed I just couldn't remember it.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Jonathan Chang's answer... the blindly obvious thing you're missing is that you can just select the columns and issue the rowMeans command.  That'll give vector of the means for each row.  His command gets the row means for each group of unique column names and was exactly what I was going to write.  With your sample data the result of his command is two lists.

rowMeans is also very fast.

To break it down, to get the means of all of your memory columns only is just

```
rowMeans(df[,colnames(df) == 'Memory']) #or from you example, rowMeans(df[,1:5])
```

It's the simplest complete correct answer, vote him up and mark him correct if you like it.

(BTW, I also liked Jo's recommendation to keep generally things as long data.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have loaded your data without `header=TRUE` and what you have is a factor matrix, and so your generally good idea fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = matrix(1:12,3)
colnames(m) = c(1,1,2,2)

m

     1 1 2  2
[1,] 1 4 7 10
[2,] 2 5 8 11
[3,] 3 6 9 12

mt = t(m)
sapply(by(mt,rownames(mt),colMeans),identity)

     1    2
V1 2.5  8.5
V2 3.5  9.5
V3 4.5 10.5
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?