# R + reshape : variance of columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm using reshape in R to compute aggregate statistics over columns of a data.frame. Here's my data.frame:

```
> df
  a a b b ID
1 1 1 1 1  1
2 2 3 2 3  2
3 3 5 3 5  3
```

which is just a little test data.frame to try and understand the reshape package. I melt, and then cast, to try and find the mean of the `a`s and the `b`s:

```
> melt(df, id = "ID") -> df.m
> cast(df.m, ID ~ variable, fun = mean)
  ID a b
1  1 1 1
2  2 2 2
3  3 3 3
```

Argh! What? Was hoping the mean of `c(2,3)` was 2.5 and so on. What's going on? Here's a thing:

```
> df.m
   ID variable value
1   1        a     1
2   2        a     2
3   3        a     3
4   1        a     1
5   2        a     2
6   3        a     3
7   1        b     1
8   2        b     2
9   3        b     3
10  1        b     1
11  2        b     2
12  3        b     3
```

what's going on? Where did both my `5`s go? Do I have a very basic misunderstanding going on here? If so: what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer here to fix this:
[R: aggregate columns of a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348522/r-aggregate-columns-of-a-data-frame/3349004#3349004)

Apparently, if your data frame doesn't have unique column names, they won't melt properly.

Edit:
Instead of having column names of `a a a b b`, apparently you need to have unique column names for `melt()` to work properly. Minimally `a.1 a.2 a.3 b.1 b.2`, or something. After using `melt()`, your options to get sensible levels for `variable` is either to use `gsub()` on the levels of `variable` to eliminate the disambiguating values, or to use `colsplit()` to create two new columns. For the dummy names I just gave, that would look like:

```
levels(df.m$variable) <- gsub("\\..*", "", levels(df.m$variable))
#or
df.m <- cbind(df.m, colsplit(df.m$variable, split = "\\.", names = c("Measure","N")))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid data frame because the columns do not have unique names.

Comment: didn't know I could create invalid data.frames.